# MongoDB C# Driver Update with Aggregation Pipeline "$replaceOne"

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm struggling to convert the code below to MongoDB driver C# to an "UpdateMany" with aggregation, can anyone help me?

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { URL: { $regex: /helloWorldt/ } },
  [{
    $set: { URL: {
      $replaceOne: { input: "$URL", find: "helloWorldt", replacement: "helloWorld" }
    }}
  }]
)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
        coll.UpdateMany(
            "{ URL: { $regex: '/helloWorldt/' } }",
            PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>.Create(
                BsonDocument.Parse($@"
                {{
                    $set:
                    {{
                        URL:
                            {{
                                $replaceOne: {{ input: ""$URL"", find: ""helloWorldt"", replacement: ""helloWorld"" }}
                            }}
                    }}
                }}")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in C# using `UpdateMany` with an aggregation pipeline (`PipelineDefinition`). The pipeline can be constructed using a nested `BsonDocument`:

```cs
var filter = Builders<CollectionName>.Filter.Regex("URL", new BsonRegularExpression("helloWorldt"));
var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<CollectionName, CollectionName>.Create(
    new BsonDocument{
        {
            "$set", new BsonDocument{
                {
                    "URL", new BsonDocument{
                        {
                            "$replaceOne", new BsonDocument{
                                { "input", "$URL" },
                                { "find", "helloWorldt" },
                                { "replacement", "helloWorld" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
var update = Builders<CollectionName>.Update.Pipeline(pipeline);

await _collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);
```